# Nested JSON to Data Frame

Tags: r, json

It's the first time I've had to manipulate a `.json` file, I'm unsure how to transform nested objects into columns. See the example.

```
library(jsonlite)
TEST < - fromJSON(‘C:/FOLDER/FILE.json’) %>% as.data.frame()
```

The file is imported correctly, however, some columns, according to the print, have variables nested within the same column. I would like to know how it is possible to transform these variables nested in columns within the file (`TEST`).

[image]

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: I would like to show more information, but I cannot (I still don't know) extract this information. When I hover the mouse over this variable, a pop-up appears written: list (name of all variables)

Comment: Can you try `TEST %>% unpack(where(is.data.frame))`

Comment: Issue with your image is that we cannot test.  So, can only suggest some codes which may or may not work

Comment: Does the solution below yolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rrapply)

TEST <- rrapply(fromJSON(‘C:/FOLDER/FILE.json’), how = 'melt')
```